# Sciypy Python on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, scipy, pip

I am on MacOS 10.12.2 Sierra and I am trying to use scipy with Python.
But, when I'm trying to lunch my code, I have the following problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "v2-subplots.py", line 4, in <module>
import scipy as sp
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I've locate my python :
    whereis python
    /usr/bin/python

Whem I'm trying to do :

```
sudo -H pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

and :

```
sudo -H pip uninstall scipy
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling scipy-0.13.0b1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
copystat(src, dst)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-3SMGTf-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Do you have any idea ? I think that scipy isn't installed in the right directory that python is scanning for its plugins, but I've no idea on how to fix it

Comment: Are you sure you installed scipy using pip? Also, what version of pip are you using? Is using Python from homebrew an option?

Comment: I don't know exactly what scipy I'm using.
sudo pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
I don't know how to switch to homebrew

Comment: Here's how to install Homebrew,  
which will then let you install `pip`  
[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)